# Нужно ли показывать уведомление cookies для popup окна с настройкой куки?

Tags: javascript, cookie

Нужно ли показывать уведомление cookies для popup окна с настройкой куки?
На сайте показывается popup окно с акцией при загрузке страницы 1 раз в день, нужно ли чтобы не получить штраф уведомлять о куках?

Comment: Если сайт для зарубежной аудитории - надо показывать. У них там [печеньковый закон](https://www.cookielaw.org/the-cookie-law/) к этому обязывает (судя по инфе по ссылке - в EU, CA, Сингапуре, Тайланде). Ну а в РФ _вроде бы_ еще нет такого маразма.

Comment: CA - подразумевалась Калифорния, а не Саудовская Аравия :) Пардон, иногда у меня случается злоупотребление аббревиатурами.

Comment: В интернетах нашлись страшилки о притягивании кукисов к 152-ФЗ... и хотя эти истории довольно "желтые", обратившись к тексту закона можно предположить что при желании действительно можно подвести под данный закон почти любые данные - т.к. определение в нем дано весьма размытое: _«персональные данные - любая информация, относящаяся к прямо или косвенно определенному или определяемому физическому лицу (субъекту персональных данных)»_. Крч, технически-программерски тут не разобраться, для такого юрист нужен.

Comment: По нашему закону о персональных данных здесь ничего нет потому как привязки к конкретному лицу нет. По EU никогда и не надо было popup окно, самое простое - уведомление в верхней части или футере (в хэде предпочтительнее) страницы с возможностью перейти по ссылке для дополнительной информации. По европейским правилам нужно уведомлять и получать согласие - да. Потому как это опция рекламного характера, а не прямая необходимость для пользователя (вроде хранения в корзине товаров).